# Strange setting in FormatValues[MakeExpression]

Tags: warning-messages, formatting, output, boxes

My system is:   8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 5, 2011)

When I start Mathematica and call

```
FormatValues[MakeExpression]
```

I get the following output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The message says:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where does it come from and what is a RefBox?

Comment: Why would you be interested in `FormatValues[MakeExpression]`?

Comment: @Sjoerd To make some output "prettier", I use `FormatValues` and I inspect them to see if everything is correct. BTW it seems, that the entry above does no harm, but if I spot an error/warning I´m curious where it comes from.

Comment: I see, but `MakeExpression` isn't a function that you want to pretty-print, is it? I can imagine that for `D` and `Integrate`, but not for such a low-level function as `MakeExpression`.

Comment: @Sjoerd I want e.g. to print `Abs[<stuff>]` as |<stuff>| enclosed in `\[LeftBracketingBar]` and `\[RightBraketinbar]` in StandardForm, and I use `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` for this.

Comment: But in that case you would need to look at `FormatValues[Abs]`, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Sjoerd But this is not may only setting, and I think to make `|<stuff>|` to be recognized as input, this wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Did you try the `Notation` palette?

Comment: @Sjoerd yes I tried, but I want to avoid it, it's easy to use `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression`. But this is not the reason, the error/warning above shows up, because I started M. without loading any of may packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that `MakeExpression` has any `FormatValues` at all is because there's one defined in `GetFEKernelInit.tr` for some experimental functionality (which we probably ought to clean up in a future release).  The fact that it's experimental also led to our not fully implementing the error-handling cases of typesetting, which is the source cause of the pink box.

You could just ignore the pink box.  Or, if it's really distracting, you can simply request the results in `InputForm`.  E.g.,

```
FormatValues[MakeExpression] // InputForm
```